# How to parse fixed width column text in php?

Tags: php, parsing

How to parse and display below text in php and output it in hmtl?

What I need is a hint how to approach the spaces that separates the columns. The number of spaces is not fixed so I cannot use `explode(" ",$string);` And also I am not sure if the structure of below output has really fixed width columns. I want to make the parsing function generic.

The output comes from `db2 list applications`

```
Auth Id  Application    Appl.      Application Id                                                 DB       # of
         Name           Handle                                                                    Name    Agents
-------- -------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
DB2INST1 db2jcc_applica 11446      10.0.0.209.51406.120606004531                                  WEI      1    
DB2INST1 db2jcc_applica 11448      10.0.0.209.51407.120606004536                                  WEI      1    
DB2INST1 db2jcc_applica 13762      10.0.0.206.57473.120606024909                                  DOM_BUGS 1    
ADMIN    db2jcc_applica 15220      10.0.0.210.52248.120606045402                                  RATIONAL 1    
DB2INST1 php-fpm: pool  16546      127.0.0.2.35530.120606065726                                   KON      1    
DB2INST1 db2jcc_applica 16547      10.0.0.202.52042.120606065813                                  KON      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) by space

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $input);

//if your lines seperated by `\n` new line you could:
$inputArr = preg_split("/\R+/", $input);
foreach($inputArr as $value) {
   $out = preg_split("/\s+/", $value);
   var_dump($out);
}

Thanks
```

Comment: +1 you can first `preg_split` by `/\R+/` to get the rows (\R for unicod safe new line) and then by `/\s+/` (you don't need the braces)

Comment: It doesn't work for 'Application name' = `php-fpm: pool`. Note the space in the application name.

Comment: Yes i see now, the problem is there is no format how columns can be partitioned apart space. Is it possible to use fixed length columns? So for ex: first one takes 10 chars, second 7, third 6 end etc. (with spaces). You must have some kind format there, you mentioned want to separate by spaces.

Comment: The text I parse is an output from db2 command. I am not sure if I can count on it to be 100% fixed format. I use this as a workaround `str_replace("php-fpm: ","php-fpm:",$line)`

Comment: I'd argue that splitting something on spaces is not parsing a "fixed width" file.  Splitting fixed width files means that there is no delimiter at all but rather that the column numbers are what defines the data fields.  I'm commenting because I came here looking for a solution to that problem, not the above.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there was [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$vars = sscanf($string, '%s %s %d %s');
```

It is optimized for whitespace separated values, and you can specify the variable type already (`%s` = string; `%d` = integer)(; even name the variables but that is not demonstrated in the example).

Example/[Demo](http://codepad.org/RhbW4bn8):

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $input);

foreach($lines as &$line)
{
    $line = sscanf($line, '%s %s %d %s');
}

var_dump($lines);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DB2INST1"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "db2jcc_applica"
    [2]=>
    int(11446)
    [3]=>
    string(29) "10.0.0.209.51406.120606004531"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DB2INST1"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "db2jcc_applica"
    [2]=>
    int(11448)
    [3]=>
    string(29) "10.0.0.209.51407.120606004536"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DB2INST1"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "db2jcc_applica"
    [2]=>
    int(13762)
    [3]=>
    string(29) "10.0.0.206.57473.120606024909"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ADMIN"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "db2jcc_applica"
    [2]=>
    int(15220)
    [3]=>
    string(29) "10.0.0.210.52248.120606045402"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DB2INST1"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "php-fpm:"
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
  [5]=>
  &array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DB2INST1"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "db2jcc_applica"
    [2]=>
    int(16547)
    [3]=>
    string(29) "10.0.0.202.52042.120606065813"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks even simpler than preg_split("/[\s]+/", $input);

Comment: As written, it has been made for formatted string parsing. A single space stands for one or multiple spaces. One day I'll write a longer blog article about it, because it's not that much known but really some handy function.

Comment: Note that your sample doesn't work correctly for "Application name" = `php-fpm: pool`. Note the space in the application name. If you check your demo then you see that the second last element of lines got elements with index 2 and 3 null. It shouldn't be null but 16546 and 127.0.0.2.35530.120606065726. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, spaces terminate strings in sscanf. You can start to formulate character classes that could take of that (not in your case), you could check for the number of returns (here you need 4 but only get 2) and run an alternative pattern etc.. However, as you have a space in there you need some more complex parser. I was not aware of that case otherwise I would have highlighted that shortcoming.

Comment: I wasn't aware either before ;-). I'm using this workaround solution before parsing `str_replace("php-fpm: ","php-fpm:",$line)`

Comment: sscanf also supports a fixed number of characters. Looks like your output is formatted that way. You can remove trailing spaces by useing the `rtrim` function then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match` on each data line as such:

```
preg_match('~^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$~', $line, &$matches);
```

This would return `1` if matched, `0` if not.
And - more importantly - the column content in `$matches`, like the following:

```
array (
  0 => 'DB2INST1 db2jcc_applica 11446      10.0.0.209.51406.120606004531',
  1 => 'DB2INST1',
  2 => 'db2jcc_applica',
  3 => '11446',
  4 => '10.0.0.209.51406.120606004531',
)
```

The pattern simply matches sequences of non-whitespace separated by sequences of whitespace. So as long as there is no whitespace as part of the data itself, this should work on any random column length.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that will help you.

```
//To parse an example like the following categorized columns:
/*
col1          col2    col3
====          ====    ====
1 a b c d e   103     14 as d9
2 a           103     14 as d9
3 a           103     14 as d9
*/



$headings = array('col1','col2','col3');
$header = "col1 col2 col3";
//get the $heading_pos_list by parsing the headings of each column with
list($heading_pos_list, $lengths) = parse_heading($headings, $header);
//Parse each line into a row structure
$start_position = $heading_pos_list[0][$heading_key];
$length_of_heading = $heading_pos_list[1][$heading_key];
$line = '1 a b c d e 103 14 as d9';
$row = parse_line($line, $headings, $start_position, $length_of_heading);
//this works for each column and line
echo $row('col1');
//output:
//1 a b c d e
//continue on for each line.
```

You can find these functions in this article here:
http://boulderapps.co/parsing-unevenly-spaced-columns-from-text-in-php