# Parse a text file into 4 columns, with the 3rd column sometimes has value and sometimes not (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, parsing

everyone!
I'm asking for help because I'm stuck and have no idea...

I need to parse a text file into 4 columns, with the 3rd column sometimes has value and sometimes not.

I've tried a lot of options... for example, to preg_replace {3,4} spaces to the "delimiter symbol", to replace spaces into another special char... but I can't catch an idea how to manage 3 or 4 columns are in the current row

I have attached a cut of the file.
Thanks, guys!

```
           246/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   211/P 12.11.2010
           247/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   195/P 09.11.2010
           248/RD/2010    05.01.2010     13.10.2010 
           251/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   274/P 08.12.2010
          996 /RD/2015    19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          997 /RD/2015    19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          998 /RD/2015    19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          999 /RD/2015    19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          1000 /RD/2015   19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          1001 /RD/2015   19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          1002 /RD/2015   19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          1003 /RD/2015   19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          1004 /RD/2015   19.01.2015                  1049/P/04.12.2015
          31600 /RD/2015  10.06.2015                  1152/P/12.09.2016
          31601 /RD/2015  10.06.2015                   690/P/26.05.2016
          31605 /RD/2015  10.06.2015                  1148/P/12.09.2016
          31608 /RD/2015  10.06.2015                  1150/P/12.09.2016
         149130/RD/2010   13.10.2010                   870/P/12.09.2011
         149136/RD/2010   13.10.2010                  1106/P/09.11.2011
         149137/RD/2010   13.10.2010                  1107/P/10.11.2011
         149138/RD/2010   13.10.2010                   868/P/12.09.2011
         149139/RD/2010   13.10.2010                   870/P/12.09.2011
         148931/RD/2010   13.10.2010                  1050/P/24.10.2011
         148932/RD/2010   13.10.2010                  1080/P/03.11.2011
         148933/RD/2010   13.10.2010                   883/P/13.09.2011
         148934/RD/2010   13.10.2010     28.01.2011 
         148935/RD/2010   13.10.2010                  1106/P/09.11.2011
         147809/RD/2010   06.10.2010                   881/P/13.09.2011
         147810/RD/2010   06.10.2010     19.10.2011 
         147811/RD/2010   06.10.2010                  1049/P/24.10.2011
```

Comment: Work out how wide each column is and `substr` for whatever size they are.  You can then `trim()` it to remove the excess chars.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you explained how to get rows. It's not a problem to get rows, simple explode("\n"). My problem is to figure out where is the 3rd column and where is 4th one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is solvable by a regular-expression. but it is a little bit tricky. here is my abbroach. It don't care how much spaces are between the columns. it matches for specific patterns of the columns to distinct them.

```
// reduced test-data for simplicity
$data = '           246/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   211/P 12.11.2010
                    247/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   195/P 09.11.2010
                    248/RD/2010    05.01.2010     13.10.2010 
                    251/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   274/P 08.12.2010';

// regular-expression with groups to get your needed columns 
$re = '/^\s*([0-9]+\s*[0-9A-Z\/]+)\s+([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})*(\s*$|([0-9A-Z\/]+\s*[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}$))/m';

// match it
preg_match_all ($re, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// $matches is now an multidimensional array with an array for every line. 
// those line-arrays will contain columns 1 to 5 where 3 will 
// be your third column (sometimes empty) and 5 will be the last column.

// [
//   ['246/RD/2010', '05.01.2010', '',           '', '211/P 12.11.2010'],
//   ['247/RD/2010', '05.01.2010', '',           '', '195/P 09.11.2010'],
//   ['248/RD/201',  '05.01.2010', '13.10.2010', '', ''],
//   ['251/RD/2010', '05.01.2010', '',           '', '274/P 08.12.2010'],
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This part is just breathtaking! ([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})*(\s*$|([0-9A-Z\/]+\s*[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}$))

Comment: @AlexF You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fixed format file, so it is expecting each field to be at a certain point in each line.  You can use `substr()` to extract each part of the line with a start point and the number of characters that field should be. Also use `trim()` on the results to remove any extra spaces.

This is only a rough guess at the field positions, you will need to check where each field starts, you can see that I've got the `0` from the date in the first column...

```
$file =
'           246/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   211/P 12.11.2010
           247/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   195/P 09.11.2010
           248/RD/2010    05.01.2010     13.10.2010
           251/RD/2010    05.01.2010                   274/P 08.12.2010
';

foreach ( explode(PHP_EOL, $file) as $line )    {
    if ( !empty($line) )    {
        $c1 = trim(substr($line, 0, 27));
        $c2 = trim(substr($line, 27, 14));
        $c3 = trim(substr($line, 41, 14));
        $c4 = trim(substr($line, 56) ?: '');
        echo $c1."###".$c2."###".$c3."###".$c4.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

which gives...

```
246/RD/2010    0###5.01.2010######11/P 12.11.2010
247/RD/2010    0###5.01.2010######95/P 09.11.2010
248/RD/2010    0###5.01.2010###13.10.2010###
251/RD/2010    0###5.01.2010######74/P 08.12.2010
```

I used  `?: ''` on `$c4` in case the lines aren't fully padded (as in all the full length possible).

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is a fixed-width document, you can parse it with `substr`. A better approach in most case would be to use `preg_split` by space [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909702/1529324), but in your case the last column can contain a space too (e.g. `211/P 12.11.2010`)

Therefore the best approach is to count the characters, and create columns based on a `substr`. You can then use `trim` like others suggested to remove excessive spaces.

In code

```
$f = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$f = explode("\n", $f);

$cols = [
    [0,25],
    [25,13],
    [38,16],
    [54,18]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($f as $count => $line) {
    $result[$count] = [];
    foreach ($cols as $c) {
        $result[$count][] = trim(substr($line, $c[0], $c[1]));
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

This will give you result like

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "246/RD/2010"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "05.01.2010"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(16) "211/P 12.11.2010"
  }
.
.
.
  [29]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "147811/RD/2010"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "06.10.2010"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(17) "1049/P/24.10.2011"
  }
}
```